# How to trigger a multi-configuration job periodically on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, multi-configuration

I have set up a multi-configuration job which runs on different locales and environments in parallel. I have a configuration matrix setup and the different combinations are selected before we trigger the build. Not sure how to trigger these periodically(nightly build). Do i need any plugin on jenkins to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can select `Build periodically` option from the `Build Triggers`

[image]